# Make Mozilla Thunderbird synchronize all folders

Tags: sync, thunderbird

I just installed Thunderbird.

However I only see three folders: Inbox, Sent and Trash.

I do have other folders in Office 365 and I would like to access them from Thunderbird. How to do it?

PS I did already go to Preferences -> Advanced -> Config Editor and set mail.server.default.check_all_folders_for_new = true

Comment: I think that by right-click on the Thunderbird account and selecting "Subscribe..." you should be able to choose your folders.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Account Setting ->Server-> Advanced -> uncheck "Show only subscribed folders"

Comment: Sometimes, right click on folder and check like `Always check this folder when checking account`

Answer (score 11):

Right-click on the Thunderbird account and selecting "Subscribe...".
You should be able to choose your folders :

[image]

For more info see this article :
[Office 365 (Thunderbird) - Configure Thunderbird](https://kb.wisc.edu/office365/page.php?id=28427).